# index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to evaluate my train data set:

## Evaluate training

```
score = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("\nTest Results for {} test entries \
on which we did not trained the neural network.\n".format(len(X_test)))

print("Keras evaluation result:", score[0])
print("Percentage right: {}%.".format(score[1]*100))
print("Error: {}%.\n".format((1-score[1])*100))

def evaluate_model(classifier, X_test, y_test):
    confusion_matrix = np.array([
        [0, 0], 
        [0, 0]
    ])
    pred = classifier.predict(X_train)
    for i in range(len(pred)):
        prediction = pred[i]
        if prediction[0]>prediction[1]:
            prediction = 1
        else:
            prediction = 0

        expected = y_train[i][0]
        confusion_matrix[prediction][expected] += 1

    return confusion_matrix

confusion_matrix = evaluate_model(classifier, X_test, y_test)
confusion_matrix_interpretation = np.array([
        ["true negative", "false negative"], 
        ["false positive", "true positive"]
    ])
print("Confusion matrix:")
print(confusion_matrix)
print("Confusion matrix, percentage of data:")
print(confusion_matrix*100/sum(confusion_matrix.flatten()))
print("Confusion matrix interpretation:\n", confusion_matrix_interpretation)
```

problem: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
what could be the possible solution. thanks in advance

Comment: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback of the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

This is the part that is throwing the error

```
prediction = pred[i]
if prediction[0]>prediction[1]:
```

prediction contains only one value i.e pred[i], but you are trying to index prediction[1], which is out of bounds.

It seems you are trying to find of the label with the max probability. In that case use

```
prediction=np.argmax(pred,axis=1)
```